# Trouble Downloading HuggingFace LLM Models to a Mounted /data Folder on Linux

Tags: linux, huggingface, large-language-model

I attempted to set the HF_HOME environment variable to a different directory (/data/model_cache) on my Linux system due to limited storage in the root directory.
After changing the HF_HOME environment variable, the models do not seem to install properly in the /data/model_cache directory. While I can confirm that the token exists correctly in /data/huggingface, the model-related folders created in /data/model_cache (like blobs, refs, snapshots) do not reflect a complete installation. There is no progress bar as before, and the used storage space does not increase significantly, which leads me to believe that the model files are not being fully downloaded or installed.

This issue is causing significant challenges in my testing process with the HuggingFace LLM, as I am unable to utilize the models due to this installation problem.

I used the following command to set the environment variable:

**bash :export HF_HOME=/data/model_cache**

When I did not set the environment variable and downloaded the model to the root directory, I saw a progress bar indicating the download and installation process, and the used storage space increased as expected. After setting this variable, I expected that the HuggingFace Large Language Models (LLM) would download and install in the /data/model_cache directory instead of the default root directory.